# Добавить данные к data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Передаю данные в функцию:

```
var fdata = {'login': login, 'pass': pass};

function myfunc(fdata) { 
//...
   var token = 'test';
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/test.php',
     data: fdata, // <---------сюда
//...
 }
```

Как добавить к существующим данным `'token': token` внутри функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fdata = {'login': login, 'pass': pass};

function myfunc(fdata) { 
//...
   fdata.token = 'test';
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/test.php',
     data: fdata, // <---------сюда
//...
 }
```